# How can I manage settings for Aero in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, aero, desktop-customization

I want to disable certain effects, for example window minimize/maximize animations, window border blur, title text background blur, etc.

Where are these settings located on Windows 7?

Comment: They cannot be modified. You get all or nothing with Aero.

Comment: I found out how now! I'll answer my own question, take a look.

Comment: @Randolph Potter: @Winuser is talking about the graphical effects such as the shadow behind a mouse or the window effect when maximizing or minimizing windows, etc.  Not necessarily related to Aero, at least directly.  If you don't know what I mean, follow his instructions...

Comment: Righto. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (the `Run` command)
- Then type: `systempropertiesadvanced`
- Then click the `Settings` button next to `Performance`.

Comment: Alternatively, for a more standard (and also more user-friendly) approach, open the start menu and type '`Adjust the appearance`' into the search box. Next, open the first matching item in the expanding result list (named '`Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows`') and you'll arrive at the exact same menu.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you can't really change the look of Aero, but for things like your cursor and your toolbar settings, you can change those. For the cursor, go into "personalize" and there should be a "change mouse cursor" option in the window. For the toolbar, right click on it and select properties.